# Ideal SLA (service level acceptance)

Tags: probability

Let an interaction between two systems. A server system responds a request in X seconds, $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. From k seconds, the request is considered a failure (response timeout). The client system does a request to the server system, once a day.

I am want to calculate SLA (service level acceptance) $\mu$, $\sigma$ of the server system, such as in a year (365), the interaction between the two systems failures only once within confidence interval I.

Comment: I don't think you have presented enough information to determine such a confidence interval.  Even if we assume the probabilities of service request failures are independent  (so that these are Bernoulli trials), you have no information about how many service requests will be made in a year.

Comment: indeed. once a day.